# Update field in table based on sum of others

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

Users: {id, name, studentid, overall_score}
userbadges: {id, badge_id, user_id, level, score}

A user can have multiple badges.

I want to have the overall_score update itself to be the sum of all scores in userbadges where the user_id matcher the id in the user table.

Can this be done as a trigger?

I have got a MySQL statement to work in PHP where it just displays the overall score but doesn't actually update anything.

```
SELECT users.studentid
     , SUM(score) AS TotalItemsOrdered
  FROM userbadges ub
 INNER 
  JOIN users 
    ON users.id = ub.user_id
  WHERE studentid = ?
```

Comment: Why store this at all?

Comment: @Strawberry  Storing it makes it easier to do things like order users by score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query(**EDITED**) :

```
 update USERS u 
 set u.overall_score = 
 ( select sum(b.score) from USERBADGES b 
   where b.user_id=u.id  ) ;
```

Now If you want to run this query automatically say everyday then use MySQL scheduler, like this :

```
 DELIMITER $$
 CREATE EVENT update_users_table
 ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
 STARTS '2015-05-27 00:00:00'
 DO 
 BEGIN
    update USERS u 
    set u.overall_score = 
    ( select sum(b.score) from USERBADGES b 
     where b.user_id=u.id  ) ;
 END$$    
 DELIMITER ;
```

If you want to run this query automatically after an update, go for trigger :

```
 DELIMITER $$
 CREATE TRIGGER update_users_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON USERBADGES
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
    IF NEW.score <> OLD.score THEN  
        update USERS u 
        set u.overall_score = 
       ( select sum(b.score) from USERBADGES b 
         where b.user_id=u.id  ) ;
    END IF;
 END$$
 DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: This is a trigger right?  Which table do I put the trigger in

Comment: No this is an Update query.....If your run it in mysql, it will update the overall_score in USERS table to sum of all score in USERBADGES table with same user id.

Comment: is there anyway to make this happen automatically

Comment: @Jess, you need to use mysql scheduler in that case..see my updated answer.

Comment: is it possible to update every time a score is updated in userbadges?

Comment: This is an EVENT, not a TRIGGER

Comment: @Jess, see my updated answer for trigger you want to run after an update in userbadges.

Comment: and just to clarify , the trigger should be put into the user table ?

Comment: No, you need to simply execute it in your mysql. It will automatically get triggered after an update in your USERBADGE table. Check out what triggers are : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: just tried to enter it - get an error -#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '///' at line 12

Answer (score 0):

Sagar's trigger is one solution.  However, this version is more efficient:

```
 DELIMITER $$
 CREATE TRIGGER update_users_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON USERBADGES
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
    IF NEW.score <> OLD.score THEN  
        update USERS u 
            set u.overall_score = u.overall_score  + new.score - old.score                          
            where u.user_id = new.user_id;
    END IF;
 END$$
```

Or, if you prefer a full recalculation:

```
 DELIMITER $$
 CREATE TRIGGER update_users_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON USERBADGES
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
    IF NEW.score <> OLD.score THEN  
        update USERS u 
            set u.overall_score = (select sum(b.score)
                                   from USERBADGES b 
                                   where b.user_id = u.id
                                  )
            where u.user_id = new.user_id
------------^
    END IF;
 END$$
 DELIMITER ;
```

For performance, you want an index on `userbadges(user_id, score)`.